# Are earnings from Google AdSense halal?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, business

Any website can connect with [Google AdSense](http://www.google.com/adsense/start/) and can publish advertisement through it; in this way the website owners can earn money (Google collects the money from the advertisement publisher and shares these earnings with the website owner who shows their advertisements).

Unfortunatley, the website owner can't fully control which advertisement will be shown on his website, as it's determined automatically by some program which Google uses to dispatch the advertisement according the web page content/material. For example, if your web page shows articles about real estate then Google may choose to display real estate business-related advertisements.

Website owners do have access to some filtering based on advertisement category (e.g. financing, wine, real estate etc.) which he can apply so that if he doesn't want to show advertisements from a specific category then he can disable those particular advertisements.

Advertisements can also be either text or image, and the website owner can also decide to show text advertisements or image advertisements.

Now my actual questions are:

- If I don't filter any advertisements based on category or text or image then will the earning from this AdSense be halal in Islam?
- If I *do* filter the advertisements based on category (i.e. don't show advertisements from categories containing directly haram businesses such as interest based bank/financing, wine or adult products) then will the earning be halal? (In this case there would still be a possibility of showing image advertisements with short dressed woman or something like that which is not permissible in Islam)
- If I filter both based on category (as explained above) *and* disable image advertisements entirely, would the earning then be halal?
- Would it be a problem if other religions (e.g. Christianity) end up advertised?

Basically, I just need to know how (if possible) to make the earnings from AdSense halal.

Ideally, answers should include authentic sources (e.g. Qur'an, Sahih Hadith, credible Islamic research, or the opinions of well-known Arab Sheikh).

Comment: Salam alaikom
i want to share with my follow brothers and sisters that there is a good islamic alternative for google adsense. http://www.islamads.com is an islamic advertising network that only serves islamic advertisements. You can sign up for free and create your own banners and put them on your islamic website without worrying about half naked women showing up in your advertisement. Wa salam alaikom

Comment: You can consider [Google DFP](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-dfp-tutorial/14099/) and can go ahead with your third case. Most suited. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

I am not in a position to say Halal & Haram, but based on my understanding as a Muslim, i can say about the first case that its Haram; because you may get profit from advertising wine, and you will never know from what advertisement did you get the profit, despite the fact your are getting sin by doing this.

For the third case, i don't see a problem with that. But again, i am not in a position to say Halal and Haram.

For 2nd cases, i don't know, but i don't see a problem since you don't advertise something haram, and the pictures has nothing to do with your profit being halal or haram, its just about sins.

Comment: good opinion but i need authentic document (ex. opinion of Islamic scholar or any research by any related Islamic study group) so that i can feel safe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any problem in it .
as you can control what ads you want to serve.

just go to allow&block ads menu after logging in to your account.

[image]

Comment: Problem is you only can block up to 50 in General categories ... and even if is a book category then how would you know if they promote book of Black Magic ? I dont see that any one can guarantee 100 % halal income from this source ..